# Water pressure divider

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure

Let's suppose I have a water jet as source, and this jet goes through a tube and is equally divided into 4 tubes. Is there a way to control the flow/pressure at each of those tubes separately by adding a different nozzle at the end of each tube or controllable valves at the beginning of each tube? Or is it only possible to get relative pressures at each tube.

And how can something like this be implemented?

An application would be having only one horizontal tube (source of water) connected to 4 vertical tubes used as fountaines and where I want to control the height of the water output of each fountain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you want is a device called a regulator. This will limit the pressure at a given spot in the pipe to a fixed amount. Regulators are commonly available for water at output pressures from 0-2,000 PSI, and probably higher if you look harder. Keep in mind that a regulator can only reduce pressure, not increase it, so if you need the four output pressures to be equal, you need to set the output pressure lower than the input pressure so that the regulators constrict the output, distributing the pressure through all four branch lines. The regulator can go at the beginning or end of each branch line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you provide some equations about how it works exactly?

Comment: I'm sure someone can, although it wasn't really asked in the question. They will need to at least know roughly what pressure you're talking about. Very different things are important at 10 PSI than 5,000 PSI.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Bernoulli Equation is what you are looking for. Basically, the total energy in one point of the pipe is equal another point. Think about a giant water tank with water leaving a small hole in the bottom. The velocity the water is traveling at the top is very slow while the velocity leaving the hole is high. However, their volumetric flow rate is the same.

In this case, I think you could add up the individual arms and set them equal to the main line. This assumes that the mainline is equally spaced between all the arms.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange!  While your answer is helpful as theory, it does not really help his question of *how can something like this be implemented?*.  It would be helpful to rewrite your answer showing the theory as well as the implementation.